# JavaScript - Save image from URL to local machine specific path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, save

Using jQuery/javascript I am making a personal program for me and my friends to use. I wanted to have a functionality that downloads a file from an external (online) url and then save it to a particular directory relative to my /root folder.

I cannot use this on a server as I just want to run the html file locally - however it may be hosted online in the future.

I'm not worried about security at this current point in time - so is this possible to do?

Comment: No. JavaScript cannot save files locally. It doesn't matter if you aren't worried about security--the browser still is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript you cannot directly save a file to your root folder or choose the location of where the file is saved. However with Javascript you can cause the browser to prompt the user to save the file locally. Take a look at this github project:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Very informative! - I'm going to use a free hosting website with AJAX to do it now :)

Comment: You could have said please... :P